# Multiple SELECT on the same field in one statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got the following table:

```
**stats**

id INT FK
day INT    
value INT
```

I would like to create an SQL query that will sum the values in value column in the last day, last week and last month, in one statement.

So Far i got this:

```
select sum(value) from stats as A where A.day > now() - 1
union
select sum(value) from stats as B where B.day > now() - 7
union
select sum(value) from stats as C where C.day > now() - 30
```

This returns just the first sum(value), i was expecting 3 values to return.

Running: `select sum(value) from stats as A where A.day > now() - X ( Where x = 1/7/30)` in different queries works as it should.

What's wrong with the query? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`UNION` is implicit distinct. Use `UNION ALL` instead like so:

```
SELECT 'last day' ItemType, sum(value) FROM stats as A WHERE A.day > now() - 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'last week', SUM(value) FROM stats as B WHERE B.day > now() - 7
UNION ALL
SELECT 'last month', SUM(value) FROM stats as C WHERE C.day > now() - 30
```

**Note that:** I added a new column `ItemType` to indicate what is the type of the sum value whether it is `last day`, `last week` or `last month`

Comment: You Rock. Thanks for the fast Answer!

Comment: @user1782427 - No, it was too late.

Comment: @JohnWoo - Thats not humble :D.